# Why does remote SSH connection time out?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall, port-forwarding

My server runs Ubuntu Server 14.04. When connecting over SSH from a local LAN client it works fine. When I connect using a different machine from an outside network, I get 'connection timed out'.

I cannot figure out why.

My router is configured to forward external port 51887 to port 22 on the Ubuntu server, and to forward a second port 51888 to port 22 on my Macbook.

Connecting to the SSH server on the Macbook -in the same LAN as the Ubuntu server- and from the same remote client, works fine. So that leads me to conclude the problem is not in the router/port forwarding.

I have tried running the SSH server on Ubuntu on a non-standard port 22000 (and updated the port forwarding rule) with no change in result.

I have verified that ufw and iptables are not active. I changed none of their default settings since installing the server.

I have been looking at /var/log/auth.log and I can see the local connects but there is nothing logged for the remote connects, suggesting they do not reach the server?

So I **can** connect to the Ubuntu server over SSH locally, and I **can** also connect remotely to the Macbook over SSH, but I **cannot** connect remotely to the Ubuntu server.

I'm stumped, having spent several days on this and reading tons of askubuntu topics and other resources. Anyone with a good suggestion?

EDIT:
The port forwarding of the router looks like this:
[image: Router Port Forwarding]

EDIT:
Output of netstat and iptables:

```
myuser@server:~$ sudo netstat -natp | grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1291/sshd       
tcp        0      0 192.168.192.61:22       192.168.192.29:58672    ESTABLISHED 1645/sshd: myuser 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1291/sshd       
myuser@server:~$ sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: See http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/SSH_overview#KeepAlive

Comment: That refers to preventing an established connection from timing out; my issue that I cannot establish a connection in the first place - attempting to do so results in the timeout.

Comment: My guess is then that you need unique ports for port forwarding. Use port xxx for your mac, and xxx +1 for Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned I do have two separate ports forwarded for the Ubuntu and Mac machines.

Comment: If you can connect on your LAN, but not over the internet, is is most likely a port forwarding or routing problem and I can not really tell from what little you posted.

Comment: Inactive or idle SSH connections are normally disconnected by the server after a certain period of time. This depends on how the SSH server is configured.

Comment: @VishnuNK: as mentioned, this issue has nothing to do with an inactivity timeout. The connection attempt itself times out.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Using the same remote client I am able to connect to a different SSH server on the same network as the Ubuntu server. That is why I think it is not a port forwarding issue. If you need any additional info, I'm happy to provide it.

Comment: so likely a problem in your port forwarding configuration. post it

Comment: Please post output of the command on your ubuntu server (as root or with sudo): "netstat -natp|grep 22"    - and also -  "iptables -L -n"    Just to make sure how things look like on your system - for a start.

Comment: @Jacek: OK, added!

Comment: Did you assign a static IP address to the server. If not you need to do that or else you won't be able to do anything outside of your network. If you did assign it please post a picture of your IP configuration.

Comment: Does the Ubuntu machine receive any ssh requests? It should be mentioned in `/var/log/auth.log`. Does sshing with verbose output give any information (from remote client: `ssh -v -p 51887 [etc.]`) ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that the IP address of the Ubuntu server is correct and it has not changed. It is issued by the router and remains static. I can also connect to that IP address locally and reach the SSH server.

Comment: @Fiximan: `var/log/auth.log` only shows lines for requests originating from a client in the LAN (i.e. my Mac). When connecting remotely, nothing is logged.

On the client side `ssh -v` shows nothing either besides `debug1: connect to address ipserver port 51887: Operation timed out`

Comment: @markjan This strongly sounds like a forwarding problem then. Do you have the same "timed out" error when using a random (closed) port for your ssh request (also in terms of how fast it appears)? Are you sure that there are no restrictions (e.g. allow access from local network only) in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?